# store xml Dynamically using nested Dictionary C#

Tags: c#, .net, xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
    <Subject>
      <Book>
        <Name>ASP.NET</Name>
        <Author>ABC</Author>
        <Published>2018</Published>
        <Price>$100</Price>
      </Book>
      <Book>
        <Name>C#.NET</Name>
        <Author>XYZ</Author>
        <Published>2017</Published>
        <Price>$150</Price>
      </Book>
    </Subject>
```

The above id xml file i have..I am trying to store the xml in Dictionary Dynamically from the xml file ,but am getting an error like **An item with the same key has already been added**.Help me to solve this error.

Here What i have tried:

```
XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
            xml.Load("xmlfile.xml");
            Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> dict = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>();
            Dictionary<string, string> dict1 = new Dictionary<string, string>();

            foreach (XmlNode node in xml)
            {
                    dict1 = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                    if (node.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && node.HasChildNodes)
                    {

                        foreach (XmlNode node2 in node)
                        {

                            if (node2.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && node2.HasChildNodes)
                            {
                                foreach (XmlNode node3 in node2)
                                {

                                if (node3.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && node3.HasChildNodes)
                                {

                                    foreach (XmlNode node4 in node3)
                                    {

                                        dict1.Add(node4.ParentNode.Name, node4.InnerText);
                                        //MessageBox.Show(dict);
                                    }
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                        dict1.Add(node3.ParentNode.Name, node3.Value);
                                }

                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                    dict1.Add(node2.ParentNode.Name, node2.InnerText);
                            }

                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {

                            dict1.Add(node.ParentNode.Name, node.InnerText);
                    }
            }
```

How can i resolve the error..!!!

Comment: As its telling you, a dictionary key must be unique, only one may be called "Book" for example.  System.Xml.Linq is a much nicer XML API, perhaps to the point at which you can simply forget about a dictionary.

Comment: Did you debug the code? Which line gives the error? The error says that you are trying to add the same key again in the dictionary. You need to Debug the code figure out why same key is being added to the dictionary.

Comment: Yes i did . In The last 'foreach' method am getting the error and i knew that am having same keys in both nodes in my xml doc.So its not allowing to add them but i have to do the same @ChetanRanpariya

Comment: If you are using dictionary, you can not add duplicate keys for sure. So you need to first explain the logic of 3 for each loops and they all trying to add items to the same dictionary. Based on the xml you shared what should be the key for `dict` and what should be the key for `dict1`?